# Simple flow control in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, control-flow

I've read through a number of examples and tutorials and although I know the solution is probably simple I just can't get my brain wrapped around it.  Any help here would be really appreciated.

I have two functions in Node.  `functionA()` takes no arguments and returns a string in English.  The second, `functionB(english)` takes the English string returned from `functionA()` and translates it to another language.

I believe that a callback is the best solution here but for the life of me I can't figure out what the best structure would be.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? How is `functionA` supposed to get invoked? Is that where you think a callback would help, or is it about the A-->B call?

Comment: Truly, I'm not sure.  All I really want is a sure way to call functionB after functionA has returned.

Comment: Is functionA asynchronous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little unclear as to what you're looking to do (you might be overthinking things) but consider the following which illustrates four ways of these functions being called and calling amongst themselves. As a clarification, I should note that I am not writing node-style callbacks, which always take the form callback(err,result) in which err evaluates to false if there is no error. You don't have to write your own callbacks that way, although I tend to do so myself.

```
// your 'functionA'
function getMessage(){
    return 'Hello';
};

// your 'functionB'
function francofy(str) {
    var result;
    switch(str){
        case 'Hello':
            result = 'Bon jour'; // 'Allo' might be better choice, but let's stick to node
            break;
        default:
            throw new Error('My Vocabulary is too limited');
    }
    return result;
};

// the most straightforward use of these functions

console.log('Synch message, synch translate', francofy(getMessage()));

// what if the translation is asynch - for example, you're calling off to an API 
// let's simulate the API delay with setTimeout
function contemplateTranslation(str,cb) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        var result = francofy(str);
        cb(result);
    },1000);
};

contemplateTranslation(getMessage(), function(translated){
    console.log('Synch Message, Asynch Translate: ' + translated);
});

// what if the message is async?
function getDelayedMessage(cb) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        cb('Hello');
    },1000);
};

getDelayedMessage(function(msg){
   console.log('Asynch Message, Synch Translate', francofy(msg));
});

// what if you need to call an asynchronous API to get your message and then
// call another asynchronous API to translate it?

getDelayedMessage(function(msg){
    contemplateTranslation(msg, function(translated){
        console.log("My God, it's full of callbacks", translated);
    });
});
```

Note also that there are other ways to deal with asynchronous operations, such as with promises (I prefer the Q promise library myself, but there are other options). However, probably worth understanding the core behavior before you overlay abstractions over it.

Comment: That's great and yes I probably am over thinking this.  Both the message and the translation are async calls to external APIs.  Let me try your last example and will report back.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh if they are both asynch calls, you might not be overthinking it. Yes, the last example would be what you'd want to follow, generally. As you get deeper into nested callbacks, the other abstractions (e.g. promises, or the async library) will be worth learning about to make things look a little less convoluted.

Comment: The code I'm having this issue with is here; https://github.com/briantwalter/nodejs-ycf/blob/master/ycf.js  they are both async and I was specifically trying to avoid the abstractions you mentioned just because I wanted to learn how to use the basics first.  I'm still a bit lost, but I'll keep hacking at it.

Comment: I have to run a couple of errands but can make some corrections to your code later this evening. But you're going to need more callbacks. Your `catfact = yodaspeak(function getcatfact());` isn't doing anything useful for you. You're going to want to have your yodaspeak call inside the callback passed to getcatfact. In turn, the yodaspeak will need to take/use a callback, and that callback would be the one responsible for calling res.render. More later if you need it. Otherwise, leave a note if you get it sorted out.

Comment: @briantwalter - see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/barry-johnson/6e008cf0504e84fd59df) for an updated version of your code that should work with regard to calling style. I didn't feel like recreating your project to fully test, but provided all the APIs work correctly, this should work fine. I have noted all my changes with a comment containing my initials, BFJ.

Comment: Very good, I just had a look and worked in your suggestions.  Everything looks good but English catfact string is being passed in as undefined.  I'm looking into that now.

Comment: It's all working now, much appreciated on the assist.  I certainly learned something new.  Cheers!

Comment: @briantwalter - That's great to hear. Glad it helped!